# Symfony notifier - "None of the available transports support the given message" when trying to send push notification

Tags: php, symfony, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to make a simple test with symfony and push notification via OneSignal.

I already have symfony notifier and one signal notifier in my composer.json :

```
"symfony/notifier": "6.2.*",
"symfony/one-signal-notifier": "6.2.*",
```

I also set up the onesignal app and key in .env.local :

```bash
ONESIGNAL_DSN=onesignal://app-id:key@default
```

Content of the notifier.yaml is :

```
framework:
    notifier:
        texter_transports:
            onesignal: '%env(ONESIGNAL_DSN)%'
```

I am experimenting with the simplest code I was able to came up with (controller) :

```
#[Route('/test', name: 'test')]
public function test(Request $request, TexterInterface $texter)
{
    $push = new PushMessage('Test', 'Content');

    $output = $texter->send($push);

    return new Response('OK');
}
```

And I have the following error :

```
Handling "Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\PushMessage" failed: None of the available transports support the given message (available transports: "onesignal").
```

What should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth specifying the default push key for PushMessage:

```yaml
# notifier.yaml:
...
-             onesignal: '%env(ONESIGNAL_DSN)%'
+             push: '%env(ONESIGNAL_DSN)%'
```

or explicitly set the transport

```php
-  $push = new PushMessage('Test', 'Content');
+  $push = (new PushMessage('Test', 'Content'))->transport('onesignal');
```

or use YourCustomPushMessage with set transport inside.